# Handling two WebException's properly

Tags: c#, exception, webclient, webexception

I am trying to handle two different `WebException`'s properly.

Basically they are handled after calling `WebClient.DownloadFile(string address, string fileName)`

AFAIK, so far there are two I have to handle, both `WebException`'s:

- The remote name could not be resolved (i.e. No network connectivity to access server to download file)
- (404) File not nound (i.e. the file doesn't exist on the server)

There may be more but this is what I've found most important so far.

So how should I handle this properly, as they are both `WebException`'s but I want to handle each case above differently.

This is what I have so far:

```cs
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("...");
    }
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ioEx)
{
    if (ioEx is WebException)
    {
        if (ioEx.Message.Contains("404")
        {
            //handle 404
        }
        if (ioEx.Message.Contains("remote name could not")
        {
            //handle file doesn't exist
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am checking the message to see what type of `WebException` it is. I would assume there is a better or a more precise way to do this?

Comment: Guessing the answer is along the lines of checking the exception status, as in using web exception instead, `(if wEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Something) { //handle } (if wEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.SomethingElse) { //handle that }`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Based on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx), you could do something along the following lines:

```
try
{
    // try to download file here
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // handle the 404 here
        }
    }
    else if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
    {
        // handle name resolution failure
    }
}
```

I'm not certain that `WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure` is the error you are seeing, but you can examine the exception that is thrown and determine what the `WebExceptionStatus` for that error is.

Comment: I also looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx which shows you all possible status'. You are correct with those two status' those are the ones I got in each situation. I have decided to treat the 404 seperately and then else for any other exception status - as the others all seem to do with the connection and network connectivity which I will group together.